# How to connect external database to AppEngine?

Tags: database, google-app-engine

Are there any ways (better than using `UrlFetch`) to connect to *any external database* from AppEngine?

I already know about hosted SQL databases in [App Engine for Business](http://code.google.com/appengine/business/), but they are not free and will be avialable in Q2 2011, so it's not an option right now.

I like datastore very much, but customers don't like vendor lock or have other reasons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can only do so via UrlFetch.  I haven't come across any other way.

Comment: http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer is helpful for connecting urlfetch & SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to connect external databases to AppEngine is by exposing them via a web API.
Basically you need to create a webservices layer upon your Database, allowing your GAE Application to interact with the remote db through [UrlFetch](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fappengine%2Fdocs%2Furlfetch%2F&rct=j&q=urlfetch&ei=_RVQTZaBB8OVswbAq-yPDQ&usg=AFQjCNGL8_bUQrar9zaCT_yz4-B9EcNWGw&sig2=FubCEE1hAaKBcjMfjbFBQg&cad=rja) Http calls.