# External MySQL database for persistence on GWT project on Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

I am developing a GWT project that is hosted in GAE, and I would like to use an external MySQL database for persistence, instead of Datastore. Is it possible to do this? Is it compatible with RequestFactory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE offers the ability to use Google Cloud SQL instead of the High Replication Datastore.
RequestFactory does not make assumptions about the datastore you are using so there should not be any problem using it with Google Cloud SQL. You can also use both at the same time.

You cannot connect to a database server hosted anywhere else, unless you would create an interface that works on the HTTP level... which sounds like a really bad idea for several reasons.

Comment: Thanks moin! I have my app ready to work with RequestFactory and Datastore. Can you provide a link explaining how to set it up for Cloud SQL? All the samples I could find were for Datastore.

Thanks

Comment: @user411103 for Cloud SQL check out: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/before_you_begin, then look at: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/developers-guide. As for putting it to work with RequestFactory: the code is a little different, you'll need to modify that yourself to get it to work with MySQL. And of course you'll also need to setup MySQL locally for development.

Comment: by URL Fetch Python API  is it possible not sure it's the right way to do it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765057/how-to-connect-external-database-to-appengine